# invalid conversion from CORBA::Char* to CORBA::Char

Tags: c++, corba

I currently have an blackout and i'm new in c++ and CORBA. I trying to assign an CORBA::Char, but I getting an Compiler-Error "Error: invalid conversion from 'CORBA::Char*' to 'CORBA:Char'. Has anyone an idea, whats wrong with my code and how to write it correct?

Thanks!
Simon

```
class Medium_impl : virtual public POA_Media::Medium {
public:
    CORBA::Char gettype();
    void settype(CORBA::Char);

private:
    CORBA::Char type;                                   
};

Medium_impl::Medium_impl (char* _oidstr) {
    type='V';
}

void Medium_impl::settype(CORBA::Char _type){
    type = _type;
}

CORBA::Char Medium_impl::gettype(){
    return type;
}
```

I get the error in the test-Methode aref ->settype(type[i]);

```
void Mediathek_impl::test (void) {

CORBA::Char type[10][1];

strcpy(type[0],"V");

for(int i = 0; i<=9;i++){
    char oidstr[20];

    sprintf(oidstr,"medium_%d.acc",count);
    PortableServer::ObjectId_var     tmpoid=PortableServer::string_to_ObjectId(oidstr);

    CORBA::Object_var obj = mypoa->create_reference_with_id (tmpoid,"IDL:Medium:1.0");
    ::Media::Medium_ptr aref = ::Media::Medium::_narrow (obj);
    assert (!CORBA::is_nil (aref));
    oid[count] = mypoa->reference_to_id(aref);

    //here I get the Compiler-error
    aref ->settype(type[i]);    

    count ++; 
}
```

Comment: You're an array (which decays to a pointer) when it takes a character.

Comment: What is *wrong* with your code is exactly what the error message says: you are trying to store a char pointer into a char. How to fix it depends on what you actually want to do. You haven't explained what you're actually trying to *do*

Comment: The IDL to C++11 language mapping is way easier to learn than the IDL to C++ language mapping, check http://swsupport.remedy.nl for more details and how to obtain an evaluation license for TAOX11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` has been declared as:

```
CORBA::Char type[10][1];
```

then, `type[i]` is `CORBA::Char*` and the builder complains about not knowing how to convert it to `CORBA::Char`. I think that you want:

```
aref ->settype(type[i][0]);
```

or

```
CORBA::Char type[10];

strcpy(type,"V");
```